# how to add static elements to yii dropDownList?

Tags: yii

```
echo $form->dropDownList(
              $model,'categoryId', 
                      CHtml::listData(Category::model()->findAllBySql(
                      'SELECT * from category where isnull(parent_id)'), 
                      'id', 'name'), 
                      array(
                            'empty'=>Yii::t('fim','Search All'),
                             Yii::t('fim','Jobs'), 
                             Yii::t('fim','Training'), 
                             Yii::t('fim','Events'), 
                             Yii::t('fim','News')
                      )
            );
```

Jobs, Training, Events and News are not appearing.

How can/should we build this, in order to add those values to the select box ?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot add static elements by using the `$htmlOptions` parameter. Here is how I do it:

```
$data = CHtml::listData(Category::model()->findAllBySql(
                        'SELECT * from category where isnull(parent_id)'), 
                        'id', 'name');
// Add extra options here: I am actually prepending with this syntax,
// but you are free to append or interleave instead. Array keys are the values.
$static = array(
    'jobs'     => Yii::t('fim','Jobs'), 
    'training' => Yii::t('fim','Training'), 
    'events'   => Yii::t('fim','Events'), 
    'news'     => Yii::t('fim','News'),
);

echo $form->dropDownList(
    $model,
    'categoryId',
    $static + $data,
    array('empty'=>Yii::t('fim','Search All')));
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, what i did is i added jquery code, i append an html option

```
    $("#categoryId").append("<option value='0'>Additional Field</option>");
```

its less complicated and it works for me